# Failed to propagate context in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

Getting this new error in Azure Function App. Both on cloud and running locally with emulation.

```
ApplicationInsights:Failed to propagate context in Azure Functions 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'customProperties')
at AzureFunctionsHook.<anonymous> (...\node_modules\applicationinsights\out\AutoCollection\AzureFunctionsHook.js:84:42)
at step (...\node_modules\applicationinsights\out\AutoCollection\AzureFunctionsHook.js:33:23)
at Object.next (...\node_modules\applicationinsights\out\AutoCollection\AzureFunctionsHook.js:14:53)   
at ...\node_modules\applicationinsights\out\AutoCollection\AzureFunctionsHook.js:8:71
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at __awaiter (...\node_modules\applicationinsights\out\AutoCollection\AzureFunctionsHook.js:4:12)
at ...\node_modules\applicationinsights\out\AutoCollection\AzureFunctionsHook.js:78:136
at t.WorkerChannel.<anonymous> (...\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.14.1\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\dist\src\worker-bundle.js:2:16100)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at ...\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.14.1\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\dist\src\worker-bundle.js:2:14637
```

There's no additional trace information. And the exceptions don't show up in the application insights log query interface.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does the function app have configuration settings for APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY or APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING, and are they set correctly?  Do you see any issues on the function app's "Application Insights" blade?

Comment: It looks like you're adding customProperties to your telemetry.  What happens if you comment out those properties and no longer try to send them?

Comment: I think this error suggests an issue with propagating context in Azure Functions, likely related to Application Insights integration